# Using string variables within a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a variable which I define by:

```
  if($(this).hasClass('firstName')){
        lastname = $(this)
            current='.first-name'
        }
```

I have to use this variable in jQuery selector.
I tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
$('.invitePartners' + current + '[data-index]')
```

Comment: It should work - `$('.invitePartners.first-name[data-index]')`, show the whole code and exactly what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: Shaunak D - I have to use the var itself

Comment: That is what I have said, your `var` when appended/concatenated will look like above, which looks valid.

Answer (score 1):

They way you are trying to do will compile as:
$('.invitePartners.first-name[data-index]');

I think, you need spaces between them to find heirarchical DOM elements:

```
$('.invitePartners ' + current + ' [data-index]');
```

[Space added after '.invitePartners' and before '[data-index]'], hopefully this will resolve your problem

OR

```
if($(this).hasClass('firstName')){
        lastname = $(this)
            current=' .first-name ';
        }
```

add space on both sides of current var value.

Answer (score 0):

May be spaces between them as you may want descendant selector.

```
$('.invitePartners ' + current + ' [data-index]')
```

Else you will have a value like `.invitePartners.first-name[data-index]` which will look for an element with class `invitePartners` and `first-name` which also have an attribute `data-index`(something like `<div class="invitePartners first-name" data-index="1"></div>`)

Comment: Arun P Johny- the class of the current supposed to be a child of the .invitePartners , and a parent of [data-index]-   $('.invitePartners .className [data-index]')

Comment: @SaritSara so use `$('.invitePartners ' + current + ' [data-index]')`